# trouble with forking 3 grandchildren from children, order and PID and PPIDs not right

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

Hi I have a question about creating more children with fork() that is based upon an earlier question that I asked [using fork() to make 3 children out of 1 parent in C (not C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837045/using-fork-to-make-3-children-out-of-1-parent-in-c-not-c)

I want my output to look something like this (#s are simplfied and just used to illustrate the order)

```
[grandpa]hi am I PID 1234 and I come from ####(dont care what this number is)
  [dad] hi i am PID 2111 and I come from PPID 1234
    [son] hi i am PID 3111 and I come from PPID 2111
    [son] hi i am PID 3112 and I come from PPID 2111
    [son] hi i am PID 3113 and I come from PPID 2111
  [dad] hi i am PID 2112 and I come from PPID 1234
    [son] hi i am PID 3111 and I come from PPID 2112
    [son] hi i am PID 3112 and I come from PPID 2112
    [son] hi i am PID 3113 and I come from PPID 2112
  [dad] hi i am PID 2113 and I come from PPID 1234
    [son] hi i am PID 3111 and I come from PPID 2113
    [son] hi i am PID 3112 and I come from PPID 2113
    [son] hi i am PID 3113 and I come from PPID 2113
```

but my output looks like this:

[image: output]

It seems ok at the end there with regards to the dad ppid except the last one and most of the PIDs seem out of order. I don't know why there is one son, then 5, then 3 sons. Here is my code:

```
int grandforking(null)
{
    Gen1 (null);       
    return 0;
}

int Gen1 (null)
{    
  void about(char *);
  int i=0;
  int j=0;  
  about("grandpa");    
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
        pid_t child = 0;
        child = fork();
        if (child < 0) 
        { //unable to fork error
            perror ("Unable to fork");
            exit(-1);
        }    
        else if (child == 0)
        { //child process
             Gen2 (null);
             exit(0);
        }    
        else 
        { //parent process    
              //(do nothing)
        }    
  }   
  for(j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
  {
     wait(NULL);//wait for parent to acknowledge child process
  }
return 0;
}

int Gen2 (null)
{   
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  about("dad");
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
        pid_t child = 0;
        child = fork();
        if (child < 0)
        { //unable to fork error
            perror ("Unable to fork");
            exit(-1);
         }    
         else if (child == 0)
         { //child process
             about ("son");
             exit(0);
         }   
         else 
         { //parent process
            //(do nothing)
         }
  }
  for(j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
  {
    wait(NULL);//wait for parent to acknowledge child process
  }
   return 0;    
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to clarify what language it is, just use the tags for that. You think the community is aware of the difference between [tag:c] and [tag:c++] and in fact it's quite common to see question mixing the tags and we keep telling them c is not c++.

Comment: ahh just trying to be helpful in my title since sometimes I get asked if it's C++ when I just put C

Comment: The code is working correctly. You have three dads that were spawned from 5841, and three sons from 5842, three sons from 5843, and three sons from 5850. The order of the printfs between uncles and nephews is not something that the code is attempting to control. The code only guarantees that a dad prints before any of its sons.

Comment: I've found that all the superfluous words and English make it harder to debug in general and see what's going on. I'd just list `<pid> (parent: <pid>)` and indent as necessary to indicate parent/child relationships and show the process tree.

Comment: ok thanks everyone. If anyone has any ideas on how to format the output better( kind of like what Arlie said) I think I'll just leave it as is for now.

Comment: I explained how to format the output. Keep it succinct and skip the superfluous words they clutter and confuse it for trying to see the process tree.

Comment: Your code formatting as posted is *horrible* You should look at C programs as presented in the classic text or in code repositories online. You have too much vert. space making it much harder to read and debug. Your use of braces is confusing. You should not put a space between the function name and opening paren. You should put a space between the trailing { and the code. And you should not collapse the } onto the same line but make it line up with the if or for, etc... And also you shouldn't waste space for stubs that do nothing unless you are saving it for later.

Comment: For `if` branches that do nothing in a loop, often, rather than an empty block with a comment in it, 'continue' key word is what you want.

Comment: Your code example and output were difficult to read. I've been coding for 30 years, many companies. Seen millions of lines of C code, written and debugged everything, so I know something about maintaining and properly formatting code. If you study the matter you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once processes are launched, the scheduler can and will run them in any order it wishes. This includes running several at the same time, if you have more than one processor. (Like everyone, these days.)

It can certainly launch a child, run that child for a while, and only then go back to the parent to print the message.

You'd get slightly better ordering if you had the identifying printf before the parent spawned its children.

But the only way you'll get lockstep ordering is if you do something like:

- identify oneself
- start of loop

  - launch a child
  - wait for child to complete
- exit after all children have completed

Comment: do you think the actual grouping of the grandparent >>> parent >>> grandchild is right or is it simply that they are not being displayed on the screen in the correct order? From what you said it sounds like it's the latter